# What should I do to make webview resizes images in the content to fit the mobile screen

Tags: android, react-native, webview

webview doesn't resize images in the content to fit the mobile screen.

I use from "react-native-webview" and I'm trying to make the web content fit into the mobile screen but images don't fit at all causing horizontal scrolling.

I used `scalesPageToFit={true}` but it didn't help.
I also tried `style={{ flex: 1, width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}` and `style={{ flex: 1, width:'100%', alignSelf: 'stretch' }}` but I didn't get any changes.
I tried `scrollEnabled={false}` but nothing works.

- "react-native": "0.57.8"
- "react": "16.6.3"
- "react-native-webview": "^2.14.3"
- android
- redmi note 4 - android version 7.0
- windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
webUrl = "<a href=\""+your_image_url+"\" target=\"_blank\">\n" +
    "  <img src=\""+your_image_url+"\" style=\"width: 400px; height: 180px;\">\n" +
    "</a>";

your_webView.loadData(webUrl, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setLoadWithOverviewMode(boolean))? Per the documentation:

> Sets whether the WebView loads pages in overview mode, that is, zooms out the content to fit on screen by width. This setting is taken into account when the content width is greater than the width of the WebView control...

This sounds like exactly what you want.

You can also try an HTML-based solution with the [meta viewport tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag), but you should make sure to call [`setUseWideViewPort(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUseWideViewPort(boolean)), otherwise WebView won't respect the value.

Comment: Sorry, but could you please explain more?! as I'm a beginner at React native and I have no previous experience with android or java. 
I tried to modify [ReactWebViewManager.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/webview/ReactWebViewManager.java) file to contain this line `setting.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);` inside `protected WebView createViewInstance` function and run command `react-native run-android start` but nothing changes.

Comment: loadWithOverviewMode is in webview.settings.loadWithOverviewMode

Answer (score 0):

Add before `</body>` inside a `<script>` tag.

It automatically resizes all images.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('img').each(function() {
    var WidthMax = 350;
    var HeightMax = 300;
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();

    if ((width > WidthMax) || (height > HeightMax)) {
      if (width > WidthMax)
        $(this).css("width", WidthMax);
      else
        $(this).css("height", HeightMax);
      $(this).mouseover(function() {}

      ).mouseout(function() {
          $('#out').remove();
        }

      ).mousemove(function(e) {

        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY;
        $('#out').css("top", y + 15);
        $('#out').css("left", x + 15);
      });
    }
  });
});
```